# How to get values from custom cells with textfield UITableView?

Tags: ios4, uitableview, uitextfield

I have created a UITableView which function like this section 0 2 custom cells (First name,last name with UITextFields) section 1 (tap a button on header insert a new cell with textfield + a Button to change the title) section 2 (tap a button on header insert a new cell with textfield + a Button to change the title) section 3 (tap a button on header insert a new cell with textfield + a Button to change the title ). Now suppose I create a 3-3 rows in each section except section 0. How do i dynamically get all the textfields values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a datasource for your TableView.
This source should be updated automatically everytime you insert a new cell.
So if you iterate through the array containing your datasource there should also be the values of the textfield somewhere.

If this isn't the case you should think about the way you are adding the new cells.
Usually in your datasource there should be reserved some space for the data in the textfield.
If you create a new Cell now, the space reserved for the data of the textfield should be updated with the new data.

If I understand you correctly you have a cell with a lable and a textfield and a button.
you create a cell, enter some text in the textfield and then press the button.
then the content of the textfield should be displayed in the label.

If i'm wrong please shove me in the right direction. Maybe you can post some screenshots or something.

> !!!!! Wrong approach !!!!!!!
>
> Iterate through your cells you get
>   from the method
>
> ```
> [tableView visibleCells];
> ```
>
> and then get the value from the
>   textField contained in the cell via
>
> ```
> NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: [tableView
> ```
>
> visibleCells]];
>       [[(YourCellSubClass*)myArray textfield] text];
>
> I have not tested this, but i think it
>   should work.
>
> !!!!!! Wrong approach end !!!!!!

Comment: @Maverick1st what If I have more than 25 cells?

Comment: OK, I just found out my answer was complet crap. I'll edit it with the better answer i have now. :)

Comment: @maverick1st you are going in a wrong direction. I am creating a custom add contact like screen iphone's contatcs app has. But a little bit different. I have 1st section static. 2,3,4 section have a section header view. Header view have a button through which I add a new cell. So for section 2 I have an array like phonelist similarly for section 3 emaillist and for 4 otherDetails. So when I Tap on header button I show a table with  some options. When one option is selected I add the selected text into array corresponding to section header selection.

Comment: @Rahul And on which point to you want to get the content of the textfields?

Comment: On tap of a button. Suppose I want to save complete details in sqlite database.

Comment: Maybe you should write the content of the textfield to a variable you have access to, when it resigns responder. Thus you can store all the text of the textfields in maybe an array and use them later, when you press the button.

Answer (score 1):

you must set delegate of `UITextField` the `ViewController` in which you have the `UITableView`. then override this method to get the text of focused textfield `textField:DidEndEditing`. 
Also you can set the tags for each `UITextfield` to differentiate them.